# How to slide a image from one position to another in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have requirement that , In my application I have an image that occupy the full screen,after 5 second it will slowly slide up upto 50% of the screen and stay there. Remaining 50% screen occupy another image same like it slide up from bottom to below of first image.
How I can do it?

Comment: There are many ways to do it.. CAn you say Y you need it for? so that i may be able to help you .

Comment: my client requirement is like that so please help me.

Comment: I am asking the use of it. Is it for showing a slide menu sort of a thing?

Comment: The upper portion for showing image and lower part for gallery view for display list images that related to above image.

Answer (score 0):

You can start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html).
There is a lot to learn on Android Animation and Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the animations API of android.

however, since the handling of animations has changed between pre-honeycomb and honeycomb, you need to decide which android versions are supported on your app.

if you have the minSdk to 11 or above, you can use the new API .

otherwise you can use the old API . you can also use the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library that mimics the way the new API works, using the old API.

for both, you can look at the API demos of google (or the library i've mentioned).

so, for making the animation you've mentioned, you can use the ScaleAnimation (old API) and use the screen width as the parameters for before and after .